# MIPS where to put recursive calls in a palindrome problem

Tags: recursion, mips, palindrome, mips32

I am writing a program that accepts a user given strings and will output 1 if it is a palindrome or 0 if it isn't.  It has to use recursion, however I am having trouble figuring out how to format the jal and jr statements so that recursion works properly.

```
main:
    la $a0, askForString        #simple text asking for user input
    li $v0, 4                  
    syscall

    li $v0, 8                 
    la $a0, userInput          #points a0 to space allocated to get user input
    li $a1, 41                 #allows the user to enter input up to 40 characters
    syscall

    la $a0, userInput        
    li $v0, 4               
    syscall

    lw $s0, userInput
    j palindrome

palindrome:
    la $a1, userInput
    addu $a1,$a1,$s1   
    lbu $a0,($a1)      # read the character in $s1 spot of the user inputted word

    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $a0, 0($sp)      #add the specific character to the stack so it can be looked at later

    addi $s1, $s1, 1    #advance the count to look at the next character

    jal palindrome

    lw $t0, 0($sp)      #load the last letter of the user given word from the stack
    addi $sp, $sp, 4

    la $a1, userInput
    addu $a1,$a1,$s2   
    lbu $a0,($a1)      # read the character in $s2 spot of the user inputted word

    addi $s2, $s2, 1    #advance the count to look at the next character

    bne $a0, $t0, fail   #if the letters are not equal, print 0, not a palindrome
    jr $ra

success:
    la $a0, '1'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    j end

fail:
    la $a0, '0'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    j end

end:
    li $v0, 10                 #op code to exit the program
    syscall
```

I know the palindrome part of the program almost definitely does not work and has no way of knowing where the end of the word is, but if anyone could me with simply the recursion part that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I don't know that we can help given this is just a fragment of the code.  For example, where is `palindrome` defined?  Where is the `main`?

Comment: @ErikEidt sorry, palindrome got cut off, I edited it to include main

Comment: There are several strange things about this code. If `palindrome` is supposed to be a function, why is the `main` code not using `jal` to jumo to it? Why is the `main` code doing `lw $s0, userInput` before jumping to `palindrome`? Why is `palindrome` using the value of `$s1` before you have assigned a value to it? How are you ever supposed to reach the `success` label? Why is the `success`/`fail`/`end`  code part of the `palindrome` function?